# The ubuntu download site have a bug - DOESNT BELONG HERE

Tags: 12.10

## I know that this message should not be posted in this website but but I feel compelled.

---

When an user try to download the new release, `Ubuntu 12.10 Quantzal Qental`, **no matter the bits version (32 nor 64)**, the user must click on the `Get Ubuntu 12.10` button. Then the site open the *contributing page* before download Ubuntu.

Then if the user doesn't want to pay, he must click on *Not now, take me to the download* button. Here is the problem, that button has the following link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

That is wrong! Because the user will get the 12.04 LTS release.

---

You can see what I get with the following sequence of pictures:

[image: S1]

[image: S2]

[image: S3]

[image: S4]

---

I tried this on different browsers `(Mozilla - Chrome)` and with different OS `(Ubuntu 12.10 - Windows 7)` and the result is the same. I have sent a message to the WebMaster but I didn't had any response.

---

**This problem doesn't happen in some country different that mine, so I think that the problem is in the Argentina's server.**

Comment: This is a bug and should be reported as one. Bugs are off topic for this site since we cannot solve them.

Comment: @BrunoPereira I'm agree.

Comment: This bug is now solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To report this issue, please use the contact page of ubuntu.com: http://www.ubuntu.com/contact-us

> **Web feedback**
>
> If you have suggestions or corrections for ubuntu.com or
>   canonical.com, email us at webmaster@ubuntu.com or
>   webmaster@canonical.com.

Comment: Thank you. I already have notified to the Ubuntu's WebMaster (a month ago), I will do the same with the Canonical's WM.

Comment: A pity they didn't react. Who knows how much mails they have to cope with.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was the reason. Now the webmasters have been informed *(theoretically)*. Thanks for response

Comment: I must inform to you that this bug is now already solved. Thank you for quickly response.